# How can I connect to Redis server in a Docker Container from Redis Desktop Manager in Mac?

Tags: macos, docker, redis, network-programming, docker-compose

I have configured a MacBook with Docker and docker-compose, my configuration in the docker-compose.yml for Redis is the following:

`redis:
  image: redis:3.0.6
  container_name: cache`

Redis is working, but I want to access to them with Redis Desktop Manager (or similar) from the host (The MacBook). The IP of my virtual machine is: `192.168.99.100` and I tried to configure with that IP and the 6379 port without success. Anyone knows how can I have configure Redis Desktop Manager to access to the Redis server in my Docker Container?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to expose the port 6379 on your docker-machine add this to your docker-compose.yml

```
redis:
  image: redis:3.0.6
  container_name: cache
  ports:
   -6379:6379
```

You should be able to access it then on (docker-machine ip (Your machine id)):6379

Comment: Thanks a lot, I thought that the ports were already exposed in the redis original image.